# Zabbix Admin user changed into standard user

Tags: mysql, zabbix

Somehow Zabbix Admin user is changed to a standard user which does not have any privileges left and now I am unable to do any admin activity in GUI console.
Is there any way I can re-assign Admin privileges to the same user through Mysql?

**P.S** - I suspect this has happened after the last Zabbix update on below packages.

**

- Updated: zabbix-web-mysql-3.4.10-1.el6.noarch Updated:
  zabbix-web-3.4.10-1.el6.noarch Updated:
  zabbix-java-gateway-3.4.10-1.el6.x86_64 Updated:
  zabbix-server-mysql-3.4.10-1.el6.x86_64 Updated:
  zabbix-proxy-sqlite3-3.4.10-1.el6.x86_64 Updated:
  zabbix-get-3.4.10-1.el6.x86_64 Updated:
  zabbix-sender-3.4.10-1.el6.x86_64 Updated:
  zabbix-agent-3.4.10-1.el6.x86_64 Updated:
  zabbix-proxy-mysql-3.4.10-1.el6.x86_64

**

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely a package upgrade affected your user type. In any case, you can set `type` to `3` for a user, which will make them "superadmin".

Comment: Can it be done through DB ? Would be helpful if you can guide

Comment: Then that user is already superadmin. If that does not seem to match what you are seeing in the UI, then either it is a different user account or different database being used.